# Unable to access the IIS metabase. You do not have sufficient privilege to access IIS web sites on your machine. Visual studio 2015

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2015

Unable to access the IIS metabase. You do not have sufficient privilege to access IIS web sites on your machine.

Got this error when ever try to load a project in visual studio 2015.

Answer (score 0):

> Tried all the ways but none worked. Uninstalling and reinstalling IIS
>   solved the problem.